# Use LightGBM or FFM - imbalanced dataset

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, xgboost, boosting, lightgbm

I have a highly imabalanced dataset but one that is not sparse. In train there are `1328` positives out of `104000`. In validation and test set there are `400` positives out of `103000` 
Which algorithm should I experiment with: `Boosting (LGBM/XGBoost)` or `FFM (field aware factorization machines)?`

Comment: Why not try both and pick the one that validates the best? I expect lightGBM to be superior here for what it is worth since you state your dataset is not sparse, where FFM tend to do better.